# codeigniter: Trying to get property for a non object

Tags: codeigniter

**Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: admin/search_result.php
Line Number: 73**

Am trying to retrieve data from the fees column in the fees table. I don't know what is wrong with the code.

```
                          <?php
                            $term_fee = $this->db->get_where('fees' , array(
                              'student_id' => $row['student_code'], 'term' => $running_term,
                              'year' => $running_year ))->row()->fees;
                            echo $term_fee;
                              ?>
```

This is my view. Need help

Comment: it means the where for student_id and year is generating 0 rows, thus the object isnt accessible. always check num rows before accessing the result object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means your query failed. You should not assume that it will succeed. The way to do that is to check the outcome of your calls before you use any [functions that generate query results](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html).

My best guess is that one of the values you are providing isn't usable. So check your input values carefully. Make sure they are there and what you expect.

Although this code probably won't fix the outcome at least you catch the failed query and will get more meaningful information about what was done.

```
<?php
$query = $this->db->get_where('fees', array(
    'student_id' => $row['student_code'], 
    'term' => $running_term,
    'year' => $running_year )
    );

if(isset($query))
{
    $term_fee = $query->row()->fees;
    echo $term_fee; 
}
else
{
   //do something about the failed query
    echo "Query Failed. Here's what you asked the database to do:<br>";
    echo $this->db->last_query();
}
```

What happens when a "get family" function fails is that it returns FALSE and FALSE is not an "object" with any properties. It certainly doesn't have a `row()` function attached to it. So, always check what `get()` or `get_where()` return before using any query results functions.